# C++ - No matching function for call to 'getaddrinfo'

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
const char portNum = TCP_PORT;
const unsigned int backLog = 8;  // number of connections allowed on the incoming queue


addrinfo hints, *res, *p;    // we need 2 pointers, res to hold and p to iterate over
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));

// for more explanation, man socket
hints.ai_family   = AF_UNSPEC;    // don't specify which IP version to use yet
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;  // SOCK_STREAM refers to TCP, SOCK_DGRAM will be?
hints.ai_flags    = AI_PASSIVE;


// man getaddrinfo
int gAddRes = getaddrinfo(NULL, portNum, &hints, &res);
if (gAddRes != 0) {
    std::cerr << gai_strerror(gAddRes) << "\n";
```

In `Define.h` i have:

```
#define TCP_PORT 8080
```

With the code like that I get an error passing `partNum` in `getaddrinfo`.

Here is what `getaddrinfo` requires:

```
extern int getaddrinfo(const char *__name, const char *__service, const addrinfo *__req, addrinfo *__pai)
```

I am pretty new to C++ so excuse me if my question seems stupid to you, but why I get an error `No matching function for call to 'getaddrinfo'`.

The second parameter should be a pointer? Am I getting this correctly?

If so how can I fix it actually?

Comment: You pass the port number as the second argument but the function expects `const char*`

Comment: @AdrianMole to make it a string instead of int ?

Comment: Please check https://github.com/Armin-Montigny/SmlParser/blob/master/source/acceptorconnector.cpp for an example

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: port must be `const char*` and not `int`, so you can basically use: `#define TCP_PORT "8080"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`getaddrinfo()` function](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) requires a `const char *service` second argument. If this 'service' is a port number, then it should be specified in string form. Thus, you should define your `TCP_PORT` macro as follows:

```cpp
#define TCP_PORT "8080"
```

Then, you will also need to change the type of the `portnum` variable to be a *pointer* (to a constant character string) rather than (as you currently have it) a *single character*:

```cpp
const char *portNum = TCP_PORT; // "portnum" now is the string literal address.
```

Your call to `getaddrinfo` should now work.